# Can I ask about philosophy similar to my ideas?

Tags: support, allowed-topics

I have some ideas about how to describe what is commonly called "physical reality".

I tend to think that these ideas are not something novel, but I am not quite sure.

If I write (one or more) blog post describing my ideas and will ask (pointing to the URL of my blog post in the question) whether my ideas are novel and if not where to read similar ideas of other people, will this question (is my blog post novel?) be on-topic?

Comment: Your answer to this question may influence whether I decide to invest time into writing down my ideas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

But please note that:

- Questions that push a personal philosophy with no question beyond "am I right" or "what do you think" are off-topic here as this is not a blog. It's ok to express unique opinions, but you must have an actual, answerable question to go with them. (One of the close reasons.)
- Questions should be largely self-contained. Linking to the blog would be good for reference, but the main points should be reiterated in the question, so that in case the link goes dead, the question is still valuable for future readers.